# How to calculate daily average frequency?

Tags: sql, hive

I have this table `my_table`:

```
recorder_id    person_id     day
A1             1             2017-06-03 12:30
A1             1             2017-06-03 12:45
B1             1             2017-06-03 12:50
A1             2             2017-06-03 16:40
B1             2             2017-06-03 16:45
B1             2             2017-06-03 18:20
A1             1             2017-06-04 11:22
```

I want to know how many times each person passes by each recorder on average per day. For example, a person with id 1 passes by recorder A1 on average 1.5 times per day, while person 2 passes by this recorder 0.5 times per day on average (because this person does not have records for 2017-06-04). The same logic should be applied to B1.

```
recorder_id   person_id   daily_average_per_person
A1            1           1.5 
A1            2           0.5
B1            1           0.5
B1            2           1.0
```

How can I get this result?

I tried this query, but I don't know how to calculate a daily average per unique person:

```
SELECT recorder_id, person_id,
       to_date(day) as hour,
       count(*) as hourly_count

FROM        my_table

GROUP BY    recorder_id, person_id, to_date(day)

ORDER BY    hourly_count;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need the number of days in the data.  This becomes the denominator:

```
SELECT recorder_id, person_id,
       count(*) / numdays
FROM t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT to_date(day)) as numdays
      FROM t
     ) tt
GROUP BY recorder_id, person_id, numdays
ORDER BY recorder_id, person_id;
```

In other databases, you could use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` as a window function.  I don't think that Hive supports that.

Comment: No integer arithmetic in Hive, so no need to multiply by 1.0

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . I tend to do it by default, so I don't have to remember which database does what.

Answer (score 3):

You were really close.  I'd use a sub-select for this one:

```
SELECT recorder_id, person_id, avg(day_count) day_avg
  FROM
       ( SELECT recorder_id, person_id,
                to_date(day) as record_day,
                count(*) as day_count
           FROM my_table
          GROUP BY recorder_id, person_id, to_date(day) ) tmp_tbl
 GROUP BY recorder_id, person_id
 ORDER BY avg(day_count);
```

I apologize, I'm not at a place where I can test this, but it should get you down the right path.

Good luck!

Comment: This seems to be the only correct answer :-) (Just the ORDER should  be by recorder/person)

Comment: Thanks dnoeth! The OP had it ordered by hourly_cnt, just trying to follow suit.  Though I'd imagine you'd want it desc...